# Have prism modules adding some items to my File menu?

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I've a WPF application, the main windows has some regions for the navigation, a file menu(to quit the application, save, ...).

I'm loading some modules through prism+unity, and I would like them to be able to add some items in some existing menu.

How could this be achieved? Can the regions help? Or should I do something with a service and build myself the menu entry?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by creating a central service `IMenuManager` or some such.

This would expose methods such as `AddItemtoFileMenu`, `Remove` etc.

You could then manage collections of menu items that are associated with specific menus and allow any arbitrary class/module to add menu items bound to commands into the application level menus.

---

Another option would be to have a class that manages `GlobalCommands` you could then register class/module level commands into these global commands.  In turn these global commands would then be executed based on which menu command the user executed.